# ForEach-Object Loop Does Not Appear to Cycle Through Array Items

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I am very new to coding and Powershell. I am attempting to take data from a csv input, parse the groups out of each line, and depending on if a group exists run a function. If multiple groups exist then I look for an order of priority and run the specific function based on that priority.

Import-CSV to create $Records. When showing the contents of $Records it looks like:

```
$Records
 username1 "groupAll" "groupS"
 username2 "groupAll" "groupS" "groupL"
 username3 "groupAll" "groupS"
 username4 "groupAll" "groupA"
 username5 "groupAll" "groupS" "groupE"
 username6 "groupALL"
 username7 "groupALL" "groupE"
 username8 "groupALL" "groupA" "groupE"
 username9 "groupALL" "groupA" "groupE" "groupS"
```

Need to parse each line, and have a specific function run depending on the presence of and order of a group.

```
\\[i.e.]//
username1 "groupAll" "groupS"
- Does the list of groups contain "groupD"? \\ [No] //
- Does the list of groups contain "groupL"? \\ [No] //
- Does the list of groups contain "groupS"? \\[Yes]//
-- Do functionD, stop processing username1, and restart loop with username2

username2 "groupAll" "groupS" "groupL"
- Does the list of groups contain "groupD"?  \\ [No] //
- Does the list of groups contain "groupL"?  \\[Yes]//
-- Do functionL, Do FunctionS, stop processing username2, and restart loop with username3

username6 "groupALL"
- Does the list of groups contain "groupD"? \\ [No] //
- Does the list of groups contain "groupL"? \\ [No] //
- Does the list of groups contain "groupS"? \\ [No] //
- Does the list of groups contain "groupE"? \\ [No] //
- Does the list of groups contain "groupA"? \\ [No] //
- Does the list of groups contain "groupNL"? \\ [No] //
- Does the list of groups contain "groupALL"? \\[Yes]//
-- Do PrintingDisabled, stop processing username6, and restart loop with username7
```

I have tried a ForEach-Object loop, a For-Each loop, and a Switch loop but none seem to come out with the desired behaviors.

ForEach-Object

```
Function Set-Quotas {
    $Records = "Records.csv"
    $Delimiter = "|"
    Write-Log "Importing new user records.";
    Write-Host "Importing new user records.";
    $Roles = @(Import-CSV -Path $Records -Delimiter $Delimiter | Group-Object -Property user_name | Select-Object Name, @{n='Groups';e={$_.group.group_name}})
    $UserN = $($Roles.name)
    :Users $Roles | ForEach-Object {
    if ($Roles.Groups -contains "groupD") {Write-Log "$UserN - D Role"; FunctionD; break Users}
    Elseif ($Roles.Groups -contains "groupL") {Write-Log "$UserN - L Role"; FunctionL; FunctionS; break Users}
    Elseif ($Roles.Groups -contains "groupS") {Write-Log "$UserN - S Role"; FunctionS; break Users}
    Elseif ($Roles.Groups -contains "groupE") {Write-Log "$UserN - E Role"; FunctionE; break Users}
    Elseif ($Roles.Groups -contains "groupA") {Write-Log "$UserN - A Role"; FunctionA; break Users}
    Elseif ($Roles.Groups -contains "groupNL") {Write-Log "$UserN - NL Role"; FunctionNL; break Users}
    Elseif ($Roles.Groups -contains "groupALL") {Write-Log "$UserN - Default Role"; PrintingDisabled; break Users}
    }
    Return $UserN;
}
```

Switch

```
Function Set-Quotas {
    $Records = "Records.csv"
    $Delimiter = "|"
    Write-Log "Importing new user records.";
    Write-Host "Importing new user records.";
    $Roles = @(Import-CSV -Path $Records -Delimiter $Delimiter | Group-Object -Property user_name | Select-Object Name, @{n='Groups';e={$_.group.group_name}})
    $UserN = $($Roles.name)
    Switch -File $Roles {
        "groupD" {Write-Log "$UserN - D Role"; FunctionD; break}
        "groupL" {Write-Log "$UserN - L Role"; FunctionL; FunctionS; break}
        "groupS" {Write-Log "$UserN - S Role"; FunctionS; break}
        "groupE" {Write-Log "$UserN - E Role"; FunctionE; break}
        "groupA" {Write-Log "$UserN - A Role"; FunctionA; break}
        "groupNL" {Write-Log "$UserN - NL Role"; FunctionNL; break}
        "groupALL" {Write-Log "$UserN - Default Role"; PrintingDisabled; break}
    }
    Return $UserN;
}
```

Current output appears that it it is not processing each line individually. Instead of the log reading something like:

```
\\[desired log outcome]//
Importing new user records.
username1 - S Role
username2 - L Role
username3 - S Role
username6 - Default Role
```

What I am actually getting in the logs is something like:

```
Importing new user records.
username1 username2 username3 ...

or

Importing new user records.
\\ [ no other lines added to log]//
```

Is it possible to get my desired outcome? If so, what am I missing or doing wrong that is causing it to appear to not parse each line as desired? I have spent a great deal of time trying different ways of writing this script and each of them do not do what I desire it to do. In essence, I want the script to do what I want it to do, not what I am appearing to tell it to do. Thank you for your assistance.

---

What appears to be working now (20 May 2020):

```
Function Set-Quotas {
    $Records = "Records.csv"
    $Delimiter = "|"
    Write-Log "Importing new user records.";
    Write-Host "Importing new user records.";
    $Roles = @(Import-CSV -Path $Records -Delimiter $Delimiter | select -Skip 1 | Group-Object -Property user_name | Select-Object Name, @{n='Groups';e={$_.group.group_name}})
    :Users Foreach ($Role in $Roles){
    $UserN = $($Role.name)
    if ($Roles.Groups -contains "groupD") {Write-Log "$UserN - D Role"; Write-Host "$UserN - D Role"; FunctionD; Continue Users}
    Elseif ($Role.Groups -contains "groupL") {Write-Log "$UserN - L Role"; Write-Host "$UserN - L Role"; FunctionL; FunctionS; Continue Users}
    Elseif ($Role.Groups -contains "groupS") {Write-Log "$UserN - S Role"; Write-Host "$UserN - S Role"; FunctionS; Continue Users}
    Elseif ($Role.Groups -contains "groupE") {Write-Log "$UserN - E Role"; Write-Host "$UserN - E Role"; FunctionE; Continue Users}
    Elseif ($Role.Groups -contains "groupA") {Write-Log "$UserN - A Role"; Write-Host "$UserN - A Role"; FunctionA; Continue Users}
    Elseif ($Role.Groups -contains "groupNL") {Write-Log "$UserN - NL Role"; Write-Host "$UserN - NL Role"; FunctionNL; Continue Users}
    Elseif ($Role.Groups -contains "groupALL") {Write-Log "$UserN - Default Role"; Write-Host "$UserN - Default Role"; PrintingDisabled; Continue Users}
    }
    Return $UserN;
}
```

The `Write-Host` is only in the code while I am troubleshooting it.  Later I can do a Find/Replace and comment it out.

Now that it appears to be working this way, I will try to get it so I can modify the code for a `ForEach-Object {...` with the eventual goal of `ForEach-Object -Parallel {...`.  Although, that throws a wrench in my logging knowledge.

Comment: `$UserN = $($Roles.name)` expands _all_ names in `$Roles`, so `$UserN` is now a string array of all the usernames on each iteration. Use `$_.Name` to get the username inside the `ForEach-Object` body instead. If you want a better qualified answer, please post a sample of the raw csv data

Comment: $UserN = $_.Name ?

Comment: Inside the loop, yes

Comment: For now, I had to change it to a ForEach ($Role in $Roles)...  However, I wanted to say a big Thank You as a slight modification to what you put worked.  *** Does Snoopy Happy Dance ***